# Check for All fields are filled c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox, switch-statement

I have a `ComboBox` with numbers inside.

If you choose number "1" it will opening the following text boxes:

```
txt_user1 \ txt_email1 \ txt_tel1
```

If you choose number "2" it will opening the following text boxes:

```
txt_user1 \ txt_email1 \ txt_tel1
txt_user2 \ txt_email2 \ txt_tel2
```

And so on...

When I click the OK button, I would like to verify that all fields in the text boxes are filled (At least one letter or one digit)

I tried to do something like this: (using switch statement)

```
  public void button2_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      switch (comboBox1.Text) 
      {
            case "1":
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_user1.Text || txt_email1.Text)) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("can't continue");
                }
                break;

            case "2":
                .........
      }
  }
```

But it is not working.
What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Can't it be `comboBox1.selectedvalue`?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What does it mean `txt_user1.Text || txt_email1.Text`?

Answer (score 2):

You check in the `if` statement is incorrect

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_user1.Text || txt_email1.Text))
```

should be

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_user1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_email1.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to check that all visibile text boxes have a value.  Something like

```
using System.Linq;

public void button2_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   bool invalid = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
     .Where(t => t.Visible)
     .Any(t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Text);
   if (invalid)
     MessageBox.Show("can't continue");
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - but there is a problem with the t.IsVisible (its say that textbox does not contain definition for isVisible)

Comment: @MaayanCahani You did not specify WPF or WinForms so I fibbed.  What is the UI system.

Comment: Sorry. its a WinForms.

Comment: Update, use `Visible`.

Comment: Thank you, but How do I set the "t" = all my text boxes in the form?

Comment: `this.Control.OfType<TextBox>()` gets all text boxes in the form. `t` is each text box.